# How to check at least one checkbox is checked from the array of checkboxes and the text area is not blank on checkbox with value "other" is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox, textarea

I've following HTML code:

```
<form name="question_issue_form" id="question_issue_form" action="question_issue.php">
      <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>    
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question is wrong" id ="chkQueWrong">Question is wrong</input>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Answers are wrong" id ="chkAnsWrong">Answers are wrong</input></td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question direction is incorrect" id ="chkDirIncorrect">Question direction is incorrecct</input></td>                
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Other" id ="chkOther">Other</input></td>          
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="set_message" style="display:none;"><textarea name="que_issue_comment" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue"/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Now I need to check whether at least one checkbox is checked from the array of checkboxes and also only if the checkbox with value "Other" is checked then check whether the text area is filled or not. If it's empty after checking the last checkbox then give error message. All these error messages should appear on form, no alert should be there.

Comment: Have you attempted any jquery yet? Suggest looking at .each(), .prop() and .val() functions. This is of course assuming you're looking to check client side.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
            var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("que_issue[]");

  var checkedAtLeastOne = false;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              //atleast one is checked
              checkedAtLeastOne = true;
          } else {
              //error
              document write bla bla bla
          }
      }

      var other = document.getElementById("chkOther");
      var textfield = document.getElementByName("que_issue_comment") if ($(other).is(":checked")) {
          if ($(textfield).val().length == 0) {
              //error
              document write bla bla bla
          }
      }
```

Comment: @phplover it is not working is not that precise, and no i have not got a fiddle i just wrote it down, so create one and me or someone else may can tell you whats going on